# python3 - for/while loop through a list

Tags: python, for-loop

is there an another way to implement the following idea:

I'm trying to form sublists (only of numbers) using the for loop. I want to iterate over the given list, starting as usual from the first element until a letter comes up. If some kind of character (or letter) appears, then the for loop should stop exactly at that position, return the so far formed list and continue working. At the end, the main list should contain all of the formed sublists and return them too.

I tried to use a while loop, since this kind of loop should jump over all elements of the list and check simultaneously if each element is an integer or not. But unfortunately my implementation didn't work. And by the way, I would rather an implementation without using the itertool (groupby).

I'd appreciate your help!

```
a_list = [1, 1, 'z', 1, 'x', 1, 1, 'c', 1, 1, 1, 'v', 1]

main_list = []
small_list = []

for i in a_list:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        small_list.append(i)
    else:
        main_list += [small_list]
        small_list = []
main_list += [small_list]
    

print("main_list: ", main_list)
# [[1, 1], [1], [1,1], [1,1,1], [1]]

final_list = []
for i in main_list:
    item_length = len(i)
    final_list += [item_length]
print("final list is: ", final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all items in your array are single characters and not something like `12` or `AB`, you could `join` all items into one single `string` `'11z1x11c111v1'` and then use Python [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp), possibly a combination of `find()` and sub-listing with `:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
a_list = [1, 1, 'z', 1, 'x', 1, 1, 'c', 1, 1, 1, 'v', 1]
bool_list = [True if isinstance(e, int) else False for e in a_list]
group_list = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(bool_list), key = lambda x: x[-1])]
final_list = [len(e) for e in group_list if e[-1][-1]]
print("final list is: ", final_list)
```